# Check if multiple IF statements are all correct, when they aren't an action should come

Tags: java, css, selenium

I am working on an automated test file that checks if the correct CSS values are used for specific elements within a webpage. I can't seem to figure out how i can check multiple CSS values to see if they are all correct but on top of that when 1 or more arent correct that i can display a message or a error that not 100% of the values are currently correct.

This is my code right now,

```
WebElement buttons = driver.findElement(By.className("primaryButton"));
    if (buttons.getCssValue("font-size").equals("14px")) 
    {
        System.out.println("Font-size is correct");
    }       
    if (buttons.getCssValue("color").equals("rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)")) 
    {
        System.out.println("Font-color is correct");
    }
    if (buttons.getCssValue("background-color").equals("rgba(89, 192, 237, 1)")) 
    {
        System.out.println("Background-color is correct");
    }
    if (buttons.getCssValue("border-radius").equals("2px")) 
    {
        System.out.println("Border-radius is correct");
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Test was not 100% correct, check back to see what value is 
        incorrect");
    }
```

Would love it if someone could help me out, im not sure if its 100% clear what my problem is but i hope someone understands it. English isnt my native language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all what you are trying to validate is whether all conditions are fulfilled or not I would do this shorter, like this:

```
WebElement buttons = driver.findElement(By.className("primaryButton"));
if(!buttons.getCssValue("font-size").equals("14px") || !buttons.getCssValue("color").equals("rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)") || !buttons.getCssValue("background-color").equals("rgba(89, 192, 237, 1)") || !buttons.getCssValue("border-radius").equals("2px")) 
    System.out.println("Test was not 100% correct, check back to see what value is incorrect");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not nested if blocks ?

You could something like this :

```
 if (buttons.getCssValue("font-size").equals("14px")) 
    {
        System.out.println("Font-size is correct");
        System.out.println("Bot is going to check color now");
        if (buttons.getCssValue("color").equals("rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)")) 
        {
           System.out.println("Font-color is correct");
        } 
        else {
           System.out.println("Font-color is **not** correct");
        } 
    }
  else {
       System.out.println("Test was not 100% correct, check back to see what value is 
    incorrect");
 }
```

and so on..